# Call WooCommerce product summary after AJAX success

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I connect to an API to get price and available variations of the product. I made an Ajax request which call a PHP function to get the product details from API and update the database.
How can I call `woocommerce_single_product_summary` after the Ajax success?

> single_product.php

```
<div class="summary entry-summary">
<div id="loading"></div>
<script>
    function myAjaxRequest () {
          $.ajax({
            url: '/update.php',
            data: { "product_id": "1"},
            type: "post",
            success: function(response) {                                          
                $('#loading').hide();
                //do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' ); NEED TO LOAD PRODUCT SUMMARY HERE!
            error: function (response) {
              setTimeout(() => {
                console.log("FF"); 
                myAjaxRequest()
              }, 5000) 
            }
          })
        }

        myAjaxRequest()
</script>
</div>
```